# Special right-click-event in java

Tags: events, menu, popup, click, jtextfield

So, here's the scenario: I have a basic JTextField in a frame and want to give the user the option, to right click in the textfield and then, like in Eclipse or Microsoft Word, give him in a popup-menu the option to copy the text or paste text he already has created.
How do I make this special kind of right click event?

That's a short version of the program, I have so far:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestClass extends JFrame{

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField textField;

    /**
     * Main method
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    TestClass window = new TestClass();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the window
     */
    public TestClass() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize components (TextField)
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 200, 100);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setText("TextField");
        textField.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        frame.add(textField);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Mouse Event to register an event for you then you must use a popupmenu to be popped up when you click so far here is an example code for you!

```
          privatevoidformMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEventevt){                                  

              if (evt.isPopupTrigger()){
                  pop.show(evt.getComponent(),evt.getX(), evt.getY());
              }

          }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
           private void textfiledMousePressed(java.awt. event.MouseEvent evt) {

           if (evt.getModifiers() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3_MASK){

           p.show(evt.getComponent(), evt.getX(), evt.getY());

           } 

            }
```

This can also be done for right click